# Inserir um array dentro da chamada do método

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um formulário que contém um array que está na página cadastro.php, vejam:

```
<input type="text" name="NomeCliente[]">
<input type="text" name="IdadeCliente[]">
<input type="text" name="CPFCliente[]">
```

E tenho o seguinte método que consta dentro do arquivo metodos.class.php:

```
public function cadastrarPaxSingle($nomeCliente,$idadeCliente,$cpfCliente){
             // Aqui faço o cadastramento no banco de dados
}
```

Porém estou fazendo o cadastro dentro da própria página de cadastro.php dessa forma:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeCliente); $i++){
             $cadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO tbcadastro VALUES(null,'".$nomeCliente[$i]."','".$idadeCliente[$i]."','".$cpfCliente[$i]."')");

   }
```

Mas quando chamo o método para fazer o cadastro dentro do método:

```
   $métodos->cadastrarPaxSingle($nomeCliente,$idadeCliente,$cpfCliente);
```

Cadastra um cliente e não mais. Como eu faria para que o código abaixo funcionasse?

```
 public function cadastrarPaxSingle($nomeCliente,$idadeCliente,$cpfCliente){
          for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeCliente); $i++){
               $cadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO tbcadastro VALUES(null,'".$nomeCliente[$i]."','".$idadeCliente[$i]."','".$cpfCliente[$i]."')");
       }
  }
```

Comment: e como está o insert?

Comment: Oi Daniel. Ajustei minha pergunta. Consta o insert lá.

Comment: as variáveis no insert, não estão erradas? `$nome` não seria `$nomeCliente`, por exemplo?

Comment: Opa Daniel. Ajustei. Coloquei o código manualmente e foi erro de nomenclatura ao colocar aqui.

Comment: a variável `$conexao`, vem de onde?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:
troca esse "for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeCliente); $i++)" por isso:

```
foreach($nomeCliente as $nome) {
    $métodos->cadastrarPaxSingle($nome);
}
```

Comment: Desculpe Fernando, esqueci de colocar um detalhe. Editei minha pergunta.